# Gate drive circuit for 1500VDC two switch flyback converter

Tags: flyback, gate-driving, solar-charge-controller, high-side

I am designing two switch flyback converter for 1500VDC input solar application. I am little bit confused while selecting gate driver circuit, specially for high side gate drive. I didn't find any gate drive IC to withstand such high voltage. Most of them are for 650V rail voltage.

Is there any special technique for such high voltage application other than pulse transformer ?

Comment: There are some - you need to search more.

Comment: Is gate drive IC really necessary? A gate drive transformer with 1 pri - 2 sec could be a good alternative.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Its not really necessary, but I prefer driver IC due to its simplicity and small footprint of overall driver stage. Even I never tried for pulse transformer, Would you guide me to design using transformer ??